# Coax Splitter for Internet and Phone

Tags: internet, cable, phone, splitter

I have a coax splitter before my cable modem so that I can also plug in the box that gives me my phone service. A crude ASCII drawing:

```
wall
|       cable modem
|      /
|-----<
|      \
|       phone
```

This setup mostly works fine, but there are times in the day where both Internet and phone services suffer; eg: the Internet speed drops considerably due to excessive packet loss and the phone service degrades to the point of uselessness.

I've sourced the problem to the splitter. When I remove the splitter and plug one of the boxes in, I get solid performance. I'm currently using a Cable Matters 2-way 5Mhz-2.4Ghz splitter. The cable coming from the wall is 6ft; the two cables coming from the splitter are 3ft. All are RG6.

So my questions are these:

- I found a RCA DH24SPF (5Mhz to 3Ghz with circuitry) splitter online. Would this work better?
- I thought about an putting an amplifier before the splitter, but I'm afraid of boosting the signal too much. Should I go this route?
- If the above options aren't viable, what should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found a RCA DH24SPF (5Mhz to 3Ghz with circuitry) splitter online. Would this work better?

As a suggestion, try talking to the cable company. I had some rather poor splitters I bought myself and they replaced them for free. The replacements were [CommScope SV-2G Digital Splitters rated for 5-1002Mhz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0036USDLO).

They are cheap and my local cable provider had no problem handing them out. What surprised me was the overall pickup in quality over the ones I had bought. My Digital TV, cable and VoIP signals improved substantially.

At a guess, I suspect that part of the improvement may have been impedance matching (75 ohms) among the devices. I didn't see this spec on the splitter you mentioned so I might investigate this further.

> I thought about an putting an amplifier before the splitter, but I'm afraid of boosting the signal too much. Should I go this route?

I am uncertain of the behavior of newer amplifiers today but years ago I had a connection so bad that I was literally calling the cable company out almost every few weeks to diagnose this (then unknown) problem. After much trouble, the root cause turned out to be a signal amplifier (properly working, mind you) that had to be removed from the equation entirely before this horrendous problem magically cleared up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Anaksunaman. I had already contacted my cable company and they were unhelpful. But you're right, that should be the first thing someone does (and why I'm marking yours as the answer).

I ended up keeping my existing splitter, and I tried an amplifier. It sits between the wall connection and the splitter. So far, it's working well.

Comment: Glad you got your problem resolved. =)